# Select Loop Variable can't visible in loop element

Tags: visual-workflow, trailhead, loop

I'm challenging this [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/flow_reassign/flow_reassign_reassign) of trailhead. In the trailhead, "Select Loop Variable" section is visible in loop element.

[image: img from trailhead]

But I couldn't find "Select Loop Variable" in loop element in my playground. Why couldn't I find the "Select Loop Variable" in loop element?

[image: img from my playground]

I tried another way that created the collection variable at first, but can't still find.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to create loop variable when using looping elements from [Summer '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_auto_output_loop.htm).